# HorizontalScrollView - scroll after views have been added

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a `HorizontalScrollView` where views are added dynamically. After views are fully loaded, I want to scroll to specific position of newly added views. And this seems to be pretty hard for me...

How can I wait until views have been added to layout?
I tried to:

1. call `smoothScrollTo` after foreach loop where views are added
2. call `onSizeChanged` but it was fired only on activity create
3. create `ViewTreeObserver` but it seemed to be called more times that I need

So... Is there some solution how to call `smoothScrollTo` after views are fully loaded? Somewhere here on SO I saw that someone solved it by using timer. It doesnt seem clear to me...

Comment: you need to scroll to the end of the new added view?

Comment: @OmarHossamEldin No, I need to scroll to the position of last but not least view. And I know that position, but these views are really large and I cant scroll to that position until it's loaded